# [{message: "Cannot query field "route" on type "Query".", extensions: {category: "graphql"},…}]

Tags: magento, progressive-web-apps

im New to Pwa magento2 i got error [{message: "Cannot query field "route" on type "Query".", extensions: {category: "graphql"},…}]
magento2.4.2 pwa 10.0.0

i want to solve this error where it is coming from magento2

https://magento-venia-concept-nfc8r.local.pwadev:8978/graphql?query=query+ResolveURL%28%24url%3AString%21%29%7Broute%28url%3A%24url%29%7Brelative_url+redirect_code+type+...on+CmsPage%7Bidentifier+__typename%7D...on+ProductInterface%7Buid+__typename%7D...on+CategoryInterface%7Buid+__typename%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=ResolveURL&variables=%7B%22url%22%3A%22%2F%22%7D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.